# DAX - RANKX Using Two Calculations -

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have a data table that contains transactions by supplier. Each row of data represents one transaction. Each transaction contains a "QTY" column as well as a "Supplier" column.

I need to rank these suppliers by the count of transactions (Count of rows per unique supplier) then by the SUM of the "QTY" for all of each supplier's transactions. This needs to be in 1 rank formula, not two separate rankings. This will help in breaking any ties in my ranking.

I have tried dozens of formulas and approaches and can't seem to get it right.

See below example:

Suppliers ABC and EFG each have 4 transactions so they would effectively tie for Rank 1, however ABC has a Quantity of 30 and EFG has a QTY of 25 so ABC should rank 1 and EFG should rank 2.

Can anyone assist?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCsCA.png

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. You can create a new calculated column -

```
Rank = 
    var SumTable = SUMMARIZE(tbl, tbl[Supplier], "CountTransactions", COUNT(tbl[Transaction Number]), "SumQuantity", SUM(tbl[Quantity]))
    var ThisSupplier = tbl[Supplier]
    var ThisTransactions = SUMX(FILTER(SumTable, [Supplier] = ThisSupplier), [CountTransactions])
    var ThisQuantity = SUMX(FILTER(SumTable, [Supplier] = ThisSupplier), [SumQuantity])
    var ThisRank = 
            FILTER(SumTable, 
                [CountTransactions] >= ThisTransactions &&
                [SumQuantity] >= ThisQuantity)
return
    COUNTROWS(ThisRank)
```

Here's the final result -

[image]

I'm curious to see if anyone posts an alternative solution. In the meantime, give mine a try and let me know if it works as expected.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you so much. Now I know I can use this in many other tools/reports.

Comment: You're most welcome, I'm glad it worked for you. Feel free to upvote / mark the answer as a correct one - see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.